# Google Play Store reviews API in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-play, google-play-developer-api

Currently I am trying to get reviews from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rosterelf.android.phone&hl=en by following https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/reviews/list documentation.

I am using the PHP (cURL) method but I am keep getting an error saying --- `Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.`

Below are my steps what I have done / tried so far.

> Created one `Api KEY`, `OAuth 2.0 Client ID` and `Service Account` in `Google Developer Console`.

> Enabled the `Google Play Android Developer API` and `Google Play Custom App Publishing API` too.

> Going at my browser https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher&response_type=code&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&client_id=CLIENT-ID

> It gives me the `code` in response and then to be able to get `access_token`, I am using below PHP cURL code which is also working fine.

```
<?php 
    $client_id = 'CLIENT-ID';
    $redirect_uri = 'REDIRECT-URL';
    $client_secret = 'CLIENT-SECRET';
    $code = 'CODE';
    $ch = curl_init();    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
    ));

    $data = curl_exec($ch);    
    var_dump($data);
exit;
```

And in response, I am successfully able to get the `access_token`.

Now I am trying to go directly to this page in browser https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.rosterelf.android.phone/reviews?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN but it keeps saying me...

> Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project

-> I have checked the roles and permissions and it has `owner` as a permission in service account.

-> My `REDIRECT-URI` also the same URL throughout this process.

I event tried this URL to fetch the reviews https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.rosterelf.android.phone/reviews/review?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN but having the same error.

Can someone please guide me what am I missing from here and why I am getting here and what exactly I should do from here on to get the reviews ?

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using the Google api php client library?  You have your question tagged with that but your not using it your using curl

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DaImTo. Well I am unable to find any php library but I believe cURL should work as I am getting response but having errors in it.

Comment: [Google api php client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But how to get reviews from this API ?

Comment: Also if u can guide me about the issue which I am gettin .. is there any issue in my current code which I am using ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for that API using the official client library.  I believe this code is for service account authentication.   The service account will need to be properly configured see [using_a_service_account](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#using_a_service_account) [How to create service account credetinals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A)  just remember to enable the proper library.

```
<?php 

require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.2.2\vendor\autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=client_secret.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER);

$android_publisher = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);
$response = $android_publisher->reviews->listReviews('appname');   

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: How and from where to get `client_secret.json` ?

Comment: Are you only going to be connecting to your own data? or will this be run by your users to connect to their accounts and their data?

Comment: I just want to get all google play application reviews from this url https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rosterelf.android.phone&hl=en&showAllReviews=true

Comment: And you personally own that app?

Comment: nope .. I am just a developer. A php developer. Someone else developed it.

Comment: But I can create google dev account and play around it if I want.

Comment: Your going to need the owner of the app to configure the service account for you then [configure](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#using_a_service_account)   watch this [create service account key file](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A) to see how to create the key file.

Comment: Ok .. let me try to contact to the developer if that's possible. Will get back to you with an update. Thanks for your support.